# Unable to read files from ZIP file input stream

Tags: java, unzip, zip

I have a Zip file that I am trying to read. I **do not** want to use a `ZipFile` because in the future, I would like to do this for data that is not from a file.

This is what I have tried so far. Instead of printing the contents of `res00000.dat`, it prints an empty line. I do not know how to fix this

```
ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
ZipEntry zipEntry;
while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    if (!zipEntry.getName().equals("res00000.dat")) {
        zipInputStream.closeEntry();
        continue;
    }
}
int len;
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByterrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while ((len = zipInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
String xml = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
System.out.println(xml);
zipInputStream.closeEntry();
zipInputStream.close();
return null;
```

My ZIP file has only two files in it. It is a Blackboard Test bank file that I'm attempting to parse:

```
Zip file
+-imsmanifest.xml
+-res00000.dat
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Run your code under debugger step-by-step and examine relevant values.

Comment: If you’re not in Windows, try looking at the output of ‘unzip -v *blackboardtest.zip*’, to verify the size of the res00000.dat entry.  Also, verify that res00000.dat is in the root of the zip file and not in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

You code currently doesn't handle a missing entry. It just silently scrolls to the end of a `ZipInputStream` so there is no way to tell what's happening. You could do following to get exception when an entry identified by name is missing:

```
public String readEntry(ZipInputStream in, String name) {
  while ((zipEntry = in.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    if (zipEntry.getName().equals(name)) {
      return readXml(zipInputStream);
    }
  }
  throw new IllegalStateException(name + " not found inside ZIP");
}
```

You will most likely observe above `IllegalStateException` now for missing `res00000.dat`.

Do note that there is no reason to call `closeEntry()` manually when scrolling the `ZipInputStream` as `getNextEntry()` already does it under the hood. From JDK 11 source code:

```
public ZipEntry getNextEntry() throws IOException {
    ensureOpen();
    if (entry != null) {
        closeEntry();
    }
    ...
```